# Vaadin Springboot Login Form

Tags: authentication, spring-security, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm using Vaadin 24 and Springboot 3.0 . I have a LoginView class which works perfectly as follows:

```
private LoginForm login = new LoginForm();
public LoginView() {
       setSizeFull();
        setJustifyContentMode(JustifyContentMode.CENTER);
        setAlignItems(Alignment.CENTER);
        login.setAction("login");
        
        add(login);
    }
```

Now, the issue is I want to add a captcha in the form but as far as i can understand, I can't add any extra components to the existing form. Is this correct?

If So, I need to create a custom LoginView but then how do i implement the following?:

```
button.addClickListener(e->login.setAction("login"));
```

So, the work around was:

```
public void addCaptcha() {
        CaptchaCheck captcha = new CaptchaCheck();      captcha.getElement().setAttribute("name", "remember-me");
        Element loginFormElement = getElement();
        Element element = captcha.getElement();
        loginFormElement.appendChild(element);
        String executeJsForFieldString = "const field = document.getElementById($0);" +
                "if(field) {" +
                "   field.after($1)" +
                "} else {" +
                "   console.error('could not find field', $0);" +
                "}";
        getElement().executeJs(executeJsForFieldString, "vaadinLoginPassword", element);
    }
```

This creates another issue, how do i check the captcha before authentication? If setAction("login") is executed, the captcha is never checked.
Any ideas?

Comment: If you have another question, then please create a new question and
don't pile things up on a potentially answered one.

Answer (score 0):

The custom login form needs to be wrapped in form tag with POST method. So with Vaadin Java one can experiment with something like this

```
@Tag("form")
public class MyLoginForm extends HtmlContainer {

    public MyLoginForm() {
        addClassNames(LumoUtility.Display.FLEX,
                LumoUtility.FlexDirection.COLUMN, LumoUtility.AlignItems.START);
        TextField user = new TextField("Username");
        PasswordField pass = new PasswordField("Password");
        Button login = new Button("Login");
        login.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
        login.getElement().setAttribute("on-click", "submit");
        getElement().setAttribute("method", "POST");
        getElement().setAttribute("action", "login");
        add(user, pass, login);
    }
}
```

Just noting here, that in Vaadin 24.2.0 which is about to be released in a month or so, LoginForm and LoginOverlay component will have support for custom components included. See more https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/626

Comment: That link leads to some pull request witih package.json.

Comment: So, can i check the captcha before login?

Comment: Yes. I was answering your question about making the custom login form acting like login form from Spring Security perspective. So you can add captcha on that.